# Will Application_End be fired even if …

Tags: asp.net

`Application_Start` and `Application_End` are called only once during the lifetime of the application domain – thus they aren’t called for each `HttpApplication` instance

`Application_Start` runs when first user requests a page, thus when the first instance of the `HttpApplication` class is created, while `Application_End` runs when the last instance of an `HttpApplication` class is destroyed.

But what if at the time of application domain being restarted there wasn’t any user requests and thus no `HttpApplication` instances created? Will in that case `Application_End` still be fired?

Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing no (if Application_Start didn't fire, Application_End shouldn't), but you could easily test by writing to a log.

Comment: And if Application_Start is fired, will Application_End also be fired even if there are no requests when runtime decides it should restart the application domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're saying that no requests ever came, if no requests ever come in the application will never be started (i.e. no Application_Start is fired) and therefore no the Application_end wouldn't fire either.

This is not withstanding any kind of "pre-warming" code which fires up the application before requests are received in order to load up caches or things like that.

Comment: Warmup would normally be done as a request or set or requests, hence Application_Start would be called.

Comment: "if no requests ever come in the application will never be started (i.e. no Application_Start is fired) and therefore no the Application_end wouldn't fire either." So if Application_Start isn't fired, then Application_End also isn't fired. But what if Application_Start is fired, will Application_End then also be fired even if there are no requests when runtime decides it should restart the application domain?

Comment: Yes, if the Application_Start is fired, for whatever reason, then the Application_End should also be fired.